# Stochastic Computing: What is "Bundle Processing"?

Tags: parallel-computing, probabilistic-algorithms

I'm puzzled by a short paragraph found in the article on Stochastic Processing in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_computing#Variants_of_stochastic_computing). There it says:

> *Bundle Processing* involves sending a fixed number of bits instead of a stream. One of the advantages of this approach is that the precision is improved. To see why, suppose we transmit $s$ bits. In regular stochastic computing, we can represent a precision of roughly $O(1/{\sqrt{s}})$ different values, because of the variance of the estimate. In bundle processing, we can represent a precision of $1/s$. However, bundle processing retains the same robustness to error of regular stochastic processing.

Achieving precision $1/s$ sounds intriguing, but completely counter-intuitive.

Unfortunately the literature on the topic is old and hard to find. (Although I noticed that used Poppelbaum books can be had for a few $ on the usual channels.)

The article [Cutler, JR. "ERGODIC : computing with a combination of stochastic and bundle processing"](https://archive.org/details/ergodiccomputing630cutl) seems to be talking about what is called "Ergodic Processing" in the Wikipedia article. In more recent publications "bundle processing" seems to play no role anymore. Maybe it's going under a different name, now?

Any help with this (old?) topic would be greatly appreciated!